# ffmpeg single output container with 4 audio channel to AWS IVS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, rtmp, flv, amazon-ivs

Trying to send 1 video and 4 different audios to [AWS IVS](https://aws.amazon.com/ivs/) in single container. Which container or muxer should I use ?
FLV doesn't support multi audio, matroska doesn't support rtmp I guess [link](https://www.matroska.org/technical/streaming.html).
3GP and mp4 containers doesn't give me error but neither video showing on IVS

For simple try I am using this command.

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i sample.mkv -r 30 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -preset veryfast -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" -minrate 3000 -maxrate 3000 -g 
60 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vb 400k -maxrate 400k -minrate 400k -bufsize 800k -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 rtmps:someurls
```

the above command doesn't include multi audio output so just trying to send except the flv format

Comment: It's not possible, RTMP is basically just a network wrapper around FLV, and as you said FLV supports 1 video and 1 audio track.

Comment: is the flv only container that rtmp supports? cant i use MP4 over rtmp?

Comment: RTMP requires FLV, No other containers are supported.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon IVS can only supports a mono channel or a stereo track. Here is the recommended audio configuration settings:

```
Codec: AAC (LC)

Bitrate: anything up to 320 Kbps

Sample rate: 44.1 Khz or 48 Khz (it is best to match your production audio flow)

Channels: Maximum 2 - Stereo (1: mono or 2: stereo audio channel support)
```

Reference:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/userguide/streaming-config.html

If your requirement is to support multi-audio channel, AWS Elemental MediaLive has the capabilities to support this workflow. But you need to use Transport Stream container formats **(RTP with FEC or Zixi)** instead of RTMP. I would suggest you to take a look at the following reference implementation.

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/live-streaming-on-aws/